# Silverstripe static publisher breaking form submissions

Tags: php, forms, caching, silverstripe

I have a site that is functioning perfectly until I enable the [static publisher](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublisher) and all form submissions fail and i get the following:

> There seems to have been a technical problem. Please click the back button, refresh your browser, and try again.

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the above by @3dgoo, if adding an ignored class after you've already ran the static publisher, the old cached file will not be removed which could cause unforeseen issues.

To tackle it I'd suggest rewriting the above condition with the following:

```
...
if(!in_array($page->ClassName, $ignored)) {
    $urls = array_merge($urls, (array)$page->subPagesToCache());
} else {
    //If ignored, unpublish from Cache
    $page->unpublishPages($page->subPagesToCache());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using User Defined Forms, this module is [not compatible with Static Publisher](http://www.silverstripe.org/introducing-the-static-publish-queue-module/#PageComment_37369).

You need to exclude UserDefinedForm pages from the list of pages to be included in the static publisher.

To [exclude UserDefinedForm page from the static publisher](https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-staticpublisher/blob/master/docs/en/StaticPublisher.md#excluding-pages) add `$ignored = array('UserDefinedForm');` to your `allPagesToCache()` function:

```
public function allPagesToCache() {
    $urls = array();
    $pages = SiteTree::get();

    // ignored page types
    $ignored = array('UserDefinedForm');

    foreach($pages as $page) {
        // check to make sure this page is not in the classname
        if(!in_array($page->ClassName, $ignored)) {
            $urls = array_merge($urls, (array)$page->subPagesToCache());
        }
    }

    return $urls;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am not using user defined forms but it sounds like this may be related to my situation. I have built a custom form that uses the page type of 'EnquiryForm'. Will adding `$ignored = array('EnquiryForm')` to this file to `allPagesToCache()` do the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that will do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to exclude the page(s) in subPagesToCache()

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    var $ignoredPagesToCache = array('UserDefinedForm');

    ::

    public function subPagesToCache() {
        $urls = array();
        // add current page
        if(!in_array($this->ClassName, $this->ignoredPagesToCache)) {
            $urls[] = $this->Link();
        }
        ::
        return $urls;
    }
}
```